# recalculateKeyViewLoop doesn't work

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, osx-lion, nswindow, tab-ordering

In my cocoa application I want to change the key order of my views. I fill in the nextKeyView reference for all subviews in the desired order. In the view's `awakeFromNib` function I do the following:

```
[[self.view window] setInitialFirstResponder:self.view];
[[self.view window] setAutorecalculatesKeyViewLoop:NO];
[[[self view] window] recalculateKeyViewLoop];
```

where the `nextKeyView` for the `self.view` is set to the first subview I want to appear in key order.

Nothing helps and the the key ordering stays default. How to resolve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Calling `recalculateKeyViewLoop` forces the window to automatically calculate the key-view loop. You don't want to do this if you've set the key-view loop manually, as it does exactly what you've just told the window *not* to do in `[[self.view window] setAutorecalculatesKeyViewLoop:NO]`.

You don't need any of this code. In Interface Builder, make sure your window has the "Auto Recalculates View Loop" checkbox un-checked, and connect the `initialFirstResponder` outlet of your window to the view that you want to be the initial first responder.

No code required.

Comment: The code I put in question is located in awakeFromNib of the controller, the view of which I add as a subview into window's content view. I removed the recalculateKeyViewLoop line, but it still doesn't work. I cannot leave the "Auto Recalculates View Loop" checkbox unchecked, because it will break other views key ordering. So I do it programmatically in awakeFromNib, but may be it's too late...what else can be done?

Answer (score 0):

following on from Rob's answer, in XCode 7.3 you can find the checkbox in the Interface Builder for the main window under:

[image]

[image]